# Laravel 4 route conditioning

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

In Laravel 4 lets say that I have these two routes. First route looks for a slug in database, and if slug is not found go to other route. Is this possible and how would I make it work?

```
Route::get('{slug}', 'SlugController@getBySlug');
Route::get('/about', 'AboutController@index');
```

Comment: You would have to check this in `SlugController@getBySlug` and redirect to `AboutController@index` if the slug is not found in the database.

Comment: It appears to me that what you want is simply not (yet) possible in an easy way with laravel. I didn't look at it in detail, but maybe you wanna give [this package](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) a try

Comment: To clarify: Is it possible a slug with name "about" exists?

Comment: It's possible. Main reason why I asked this is if it's possible to somehow "skip" first route but with condition and that condition is checked in controller. Some pages in route /* may or may not be in database. I just didn't want for this first route to be "The Last" route in list, because if someone doesn't read my code he can add his own route and not worry about order in which they are written, also some hardcoded page can be created which isn't in db.

Comment: Ok. As far as I know "skipping" a route is not possible. However there is a [request on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1899) for that exact thing.
I personally would change the order of your routes. so all "custom" ones are up top and the last one is the "catch all" slug route. About somebody else adding custom routes: just make a specific section for custom routes. Add a descriptive comment and leave some empty lines to highlight the area.

Comment: If you don't like that idea you will have to go down the road of having only one route (the slug route) and inside of it handle all the routing yourself. Similar to the way Burimis answer works...

Comment: That request link that you've put is exactly what I wanted, but we will have to wait for a little while to get it. Thanks for all your help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave the route to get whatever is on URL, and than you can check if it exists.

If the slug exists, than just call `SlugController@getBySlug`

If the slug does not exists and it is set to whatever beside "about", than we will redirect to the same route with about set as slug parameter so the next time, no record would be found on your database with slug about while the slug on route is about.

Hope that makes sense.

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug){
    //Check if slug exists, if yes than do
    $slug_exists = true;
    if($slug_exists){
        return Controller::call("SlugController@getBySlug");
    }else if(!$slug_exists && $slug == 'about'){
        return Controller::call("AboutController@index");
    }else{
        return Redirect::to("/about");
    }
});
```

Comment: I really wanted some way to skip route, but it looks like it's not possible just yet. If I'll need it I'll use it like you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @Livyatan there's no difference between using this solution or overriding routes.If this helps you out than please mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, after checking the existence of your object, return a redirect to your second route if needed.

```
class SlugController extends BaseController {

    public function getBySlug($slug) {
        $obj = getObjectBySlug($slug);
        if (!obj) {
            return Redirect::to("/about");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: But what if the url entered is "/about". You'd get a loop if it doesn't exist in the db

Comment: If user enterd `/about`, they have been routed to another method than the `SlugController@getBySlug`!

Comment: Not if the routes the OP provided were used. His '{slug}' route simply catches everything.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to use static `about` page you need to in this case change order of your routes:

```
Route::get('/about', 'AboutController@index');
Route::get('{slug}', 'SlugController@getBySlug');
```

Now if url is `about` it will go to `AboutController`, otherwise it will go to `SlugController`